# Bootstrap Grid Setup - Having an auto-fit element in the middle of fixed elements

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I'm trying to figure out a way to make one of the grid elements automatically fill the width gap between other elements with fixed width, so together they will fill the width of their parent element no matter how wide the parent element is. Can someone please enlighten me if what I'm trying to do is possible and if it is, how should it be done properly.

Here's an image of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: if you want to have `width` than it will be hard to make responsive.

Comment: can you show us what you've tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do what you're asking for, using `flexbox`.

```
      <style>

        .row {
          display: flex;
          display: -webkit-flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        }
        .col-left {
          flex: 1;
          min-width: 120px;
        }
        .col-center {
          flex: 3;
        }
        .col-right {
          flex: 1;
          min-width: 120px;
        }

              </style>
            </head>
              <body>

                <section>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-left" style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 20em;">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-center" style="background-color: violet; height: 20em;">
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-right" style="background-color: lightgreen; height: 20em;">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                </section>

    </body>
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/xresvu75/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a css but you'll need to mention the width in % of the remaining to occupy the entire space.

```
    .container {
    width:600px;
    height:200px;
    border:1px solid;
    background:yellow;
    display:table-row;
}
.left {
    width:200px;
    height:20%;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
        display:table-cell;
}
.right {
    height:200px;
    width:20%;
    background:blue;
    display:table-cell;
}
.middle {
    height:200px;
    width: 60%;
    background:green;
    display:table-cell;
}
```

if you are hardcoding the width of the divs to some pixels then you can make use of calc property and subtract by 100% of the container width to get the result